# Antixss for Kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, xss, kendo-asp.net-mvc, antixsslibrary

Controller.cs

```
ViewData["Applications"] = await _applicationClient.GetAll();
```

view.cshtml

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ResourceViewModel>
()
.Columns(columns =>
{columns.ForeignKey(r => r.ApplicationId, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Applications"], "Id", "Assembly").Title("Application").Width(100);})
```

What is the antixss code for ForeignKey column?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? (see anwser) => https://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-grid-foreign-key-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar problem solved with HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(..) when saving to database.

```
 HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(application);
```